# Каким селектором выбрать данные элементы?

Tags: html, css

Как с помощью css селектора выбрать отмеченные блоки?

По идее формула такова: 2n+1 (только тут взялся бы 3-ий блок и не взялся бы второй, но это можно было бы исключить)

но если так указать, то css будет выбирать каждый второй элемент начиная с первого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы вроде не новый участник, где код? или потенциальные отвечающие должны сами набрать?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, пожалуйста .class:nth-child() {};

Comment: я про код разметки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, нужно определиться с периодичностью: нам нужен каждый третий блок, значит множитель у n будет 3.
Для того, чтобы начать со второго блока, нужно добавить +2.

Итого, селектор: `:nth-child(3n+2)`

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.a:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
</section>
```